# pthread_join:warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, pthread-join

#### My code

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void * thread_func1(void *args)
{
    printf("thread 1 returning\n");
    return ((void *)1);
}

void * thread_func2(void *args)
{
    printf("thread 2 exiting\n");
    pthread_exit((void *)2);
}

int main(void)
{
    int err;
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    void *tret;

    err = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thread_func1, NULL);
    if(err)
    {
        printf("cannot create thread 1\n");
    }
    err = pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, thread_func2, NULL);
    if(err)
    {
        printf("cannot create thread 2\n");
    }

    err = pthread_join(tid1, &tret);
    if(err)
    {
        printf("thread 1 join error\n");
    }
    printf("thread 1 return code:%d\n", (int)tret);

    err = pthread_join(tid2, &tret);
    if(err)
    {
        printf("cannot join thread 2\n");
    }
    printf("thread 2 return code:%d\n", (int)tret);
    exit(0);
}
```

when compling the code, there're two warnings:

```
join.c:44: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
join.c:51: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
```

I read the man page of [`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html):

> ```
>  int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
> ```

```
   If retval is not NULL, then pthread_join() copies the exit status of
   the target thread (i.e., the value that the target thread supplied to
   pthread_exit(3)) into the location pointed to by *retval.  If the
   target thread was canceled, then PTHREAD_CANCELED is placed in
   *retval.
```

According to my understanding, the exist status(int type) is stored into `tret` in my code, so I use `(int)` to convert `void *` to `int`, but the above warnings are thrown out, So, my question is:

How to modify my code to clear up the warnings?

Comment: Since what it's warning you about is exactly what you're trying to do, you'll have to live with it or disable the warning (compiler-specific, may be able to do it for specific sections of code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These warnings are harmless (in *this* case) and can safely be ignored.

The warnings are coming from the casts on these lines:

```
printf("thread 1 return code:%d\n", (int)tret);  // line 44
...
printf("thread 2 return code:%d\n", (int)tret);  // line 51
```

The compiler is complaining that you're casting a pointer (which may be 64 bits) down into a smaller, 32-bit integer.  A lot of legacy C code likes to cast back-and-forth between pointers and integers for various reasons.  In the old days, pointers were the same size as integers, so this was ok; but when 64-bit targets became more common, this is dangerous all of a sudden, since if you have a 64-bit pointer pointing above the address 0x00000000'ffffffff, you'll lose the upper bits when casting it to an integer.  When you cast that back to a 64-bit pointer later, your pointer will be incorrect, and attempting to use it will crash or silently corrupt memory.

The warnings here are just trying to help you avoid these *potential* problems.  If the value in your pointer isn't actually a real pointer, like in this case, then it's perfectly safe to cast it down to an integer if you know its value is never going to exceed 0xffffffff.

There are a few ways to suppress the warning.  You could disable it globally in your compiler's command line (not recommended); you could use a `#pragma` around the code to temporarily disable the warning (not portable); or, you could use some clever casting to work around it.

There are two data types, `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`, which act just like ordinary integers—you can upcast/downcast to other integer types, you can do all sorts of arithmetic on then, etc.—but they're *guaranteed* to be large enough to hold a pointer value.  On a 32-bit system, `intptr_t` will be (at least) 32 bits wide; on a 64-bit system, `intptr_t` will be (at least) 64 bits wide.  The only difference between the two types is that `intptr_t` is signed while `uintptr_t` is unsigned.

Since the compiler knows that these types are always large enough to hold pointer values, it won't warn you when you cast a pointer to or from them.  Once you get into the integer domain, you can then cast to an ordinary `int` without fear of warnings.  So this code should eliminate your warnings:

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
printf("thread 1 return code:%d\n", (int)(intptr_t)tret);  // line 44
printf("thread 2 return code:%d\n", (int)(intptr_t)tret);  // line 51
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void * thread_func1(void *args)
{
    printf("thread 1 returning\n");
    return ((void *)1);
}

void * thread_func2(void *args)
{
    printf("thread 2 exiting\n");
    pthread_exit((void *)2);
}

int main(void)
{
    int err;
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    int *tret = malloc(sizeof(int)); 

    err = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, &thread_func1, NULL);
    if(err)
    {
        printf("cannot create thread 1\n");
    }
    err = pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, &thread_func2, NULL);
    if(err)
    {
        printf("cannot create thread 2\n");
    }

    err = pthread_join(tid1, (void *)tret);
    if(err)
    {
        printf("thread 1 join error\n");
    }
    printf("thread 1 return code:%d\n", *(tret));

    err = pthread_join(tid2, (void *)tret);
    if(err)
    {
        printf("cannot join thread 2\n");
    }
    printf("thread 2 return code:%d\n", *(tret));
    exit(0);
}
```

First Time I Only Removed Warning, Not executed your code...

This is your all code .. with execution without warning :)

Comment: I tried this before, `Segment Fault` is thrown out. The return value of function `pthread_join` is not store in `*tret`, but in `tret`.

Comment: now check .. first time i only dried run with out execution :) @Charles0429

Answer (score -1):

Try this it should work fine

As the defintion of thread_join it expects **void **** not a void pointer

```
err = pthread_join(tid1, (Void **)&tret);
```

and for deferencing it after it returns the value

```
printf("thread 1 return code:%d\n", *(int *)tret);
```

Comment: `&tret` is already of type `void**`, casting it is completely pointless.  And dereferencing `tret` is definitely going to crash, since the address `1` is not a valid pointer value.